# Why do we divide the number of repetitive alphabets rather than subract during permutation?

Tags: permutations

The question is how many ways the word INDIA can be re-written.

I  N  D I A

There are 5 letters in this word. The letter I is repeated twice, and this number doesn't make any sense if there positions are interchanged.

So,basically the number of ways INDIA can be arrange consider there are two types of I ---  the answer is factorial 5. However the letter 'I' is repeated twice. Thus, we should subtract the number of ways the the two letter I is occurred. Thus, we should subtract it. However, we always divide it --- 5!/2. I want to understand, whey do we do so? Why do we divide by 2 here rather than doing subtraction? I couldn't get the logic here. Can someone please explain to me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The letter $I$ appears $2$ times.

So every arrangement that you have created appears $2!$ times.

Hence you need to divide the total number of arrangements that you have created by $2!$.

---

It just so happens that $2!=2$.

If the letter $I$ appeared $3$ times, then you would have to divide by $3!$ (i.e., by $6$).

Comment: @dexterous_stranger: Thank you, feel free to accept it then :)

Answer (score 3):

Your intuition to start with is good; we distinguish the two $I$s, lets say as $I_1$ and $I_2$. Then we take all possible permutations of the five (now distinct letters). If we consider *any* such permutation, say $N\ D\ I_1\ A\ I_2$, then there is always one other different permutation (in this case $N\ D\ I_2\ A\ I_1$) that will give me the same word when I forget the subscripts again. So counting every permutation of the five letters has counted *every word twice*, and so we have to divide by two to get the right answer - subtracting two would only make sense if the permutations had somehow produced two extra words.

As pointed out in barak's answer; if there were three letters the same, you would in fact have to divide by $6=3!$; given any permutation of your distunguished letters, you can re-order the three that are really supposed to be the same in any way, and you won't get a new word when you un-distinguish them again.

Comment: Can you help me here - fence error problem - http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/923663/when-to-use-end-point-date-start-point-date-1-and-when-to-use-end-point

Comment: @dexterous_stranger I think that question is too general for me to give a good answer to.

Answer (score 0):

Assume we have 4 balls , Number of ways of arranging 4 balls is **Factorial of 4 ie 24.**
Now Suppose we have 1 Red Ball and 3 Black Balls ( ie, R B B B )  . Consider Black balls as B1 , B2 and B3 . Hence we have now (R B1 B2 B3) . We can have 4 ways of this permutation

**R B1 B2 B3 |
B1 R B2 B3 |
B1 B2 R B3|
B1 B2 B3 R**
Lets denote this Set as S1.

Now we Know that Number of ways of arrangements of black balls is 3 ! => 6 .
Thus we will have 6 more sets like S1 but with different arrangements for black balls. 
***ie Total we will have 24 such permutations***
,Now as we initially knew that we will have 24 permutations of 4 balls . 
Also we now know Contribution of 3 same black balls in this 24 permutations ie 4 * 6 
Now To eliminate these **EXTRA** Permutations , Answer would be 24 / 6 = > 4 ( Set S1) and not  26 - 6 => 18 Which is Wrong. 
Thanks.

Comment: Please use Mathjax!

Comment: @ArmanMalekzade I am new here , Thanks for the suggestion .